# Ruby - How to use Hash#to_proc?

Tags: ruby

The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-to_proc) is empty, but I want to know how to use it to know when it can be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that is so you can pass a hash proc into something like `map`.

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11653

```
my_hash = ->key{{
  a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6
}[key]}

my_hash[:a]
# => 1

[:e, :a, :b, :f, :c, :d].map(&my_hash) # hash is now mappable
# => [5, 1, 2, 6, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Oh, now I can see. It works as `{a:1, b:2, c:3}.to_proc.call(:b) #=> 2`, but then I can apply it on `map` etc. Thank you!

Comment: You can event pass a hash directly thanks to `to_proc`: `%i(foo fizz).map(&{foo: :bar})`